# Regex for a file name without an extension

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex expression that will capture a file name that does not have an extension and give me that name in a backreference so I can add an extension. So if someone puts in  xyz I can replace it with xyz.html.   xyz.php or xyz.html should not be captured.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use following regular expression:

```
^([^.]+)$
```

meaning filename that only consist of non-dot characters.

**UPDATE**

added paren for capturing group.

Comment: When I execute "find -regex ^([^.]+)$", I get the error message Syntax error near the unexpected symbol "("... Maybe I don't use the right regex dialect ?

Comment: @AxelB, Please post a separate question.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the extensions are up to 4 chars in length (so filenames like `mr.smith` aren't considered as having an extension, but `mr.smith.doc` and `mr.smith.html` are considered as having extensions):

```
^.*[^.]{5}$
```

No need to capture a group, as the *whole* expression is what you want - ie group 0.