# How to filter the file list of QFileSystemModel by file name?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qfilesystemmodel

I want to make a manager that can display specific folders. 
suppose I want to filter out folders without extensions.

[image]

Try 1: QFileSystemModel.setNameFilters()

```
... ...

# get file data
path = 'f:/tmp2'
dirModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
dirModel.setRootPath(path)
dirModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Dirs) 

# filter folders
dirModel.setNameFilters(['*.asset']) 
# worked. but i want the opposite: that folders do not contain ".asset".

#dirModel.setNameFilters(['(^\.asset)$']) 
# regular expression is not work. nothing shows up.

# show window
... ...
```

Try 2: QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()

```
... ...
# get file data
path = 'f:/tmp2'
dirModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
dirModel.setRootPath(path)
dirModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Dirs) 

# filter folders
proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
proxyModel.setSourceModel(dirModel)
proxyModel.setFilterRegExp("(^\.asset)$") # if no this line, all folders are displayed; add this line, nothing shows up.

# show window
... ...
```

I tried to modify the Regular Expression, but the results were the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`setNameFilters()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#setNameFilters) only supports wildcards, not regex, so it fails.
2. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18017700/6622587) has implemented filtering the folders whose name you do not have *extensions*.

```py
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "56627022")
    dirModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
    dirModel.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())
    dirModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Dirs)

    view1 = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    view1.setModel(dirModel)
    view1.setRootIndex(dirModel.index(path))

    proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
    proxyModel.setSourceModel(dirModel)
    proxyModel.setFilterRegExp(r"^([^.]+)$")

    view2 = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    view2.setModel(proxyModel)
    view2.setRootIndex(proxyModel.mapFromSource(dirModel.index(path)))

    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)
    hlay.addWidget(view1)
    hlay.addWidget(view2)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]